# jQuery buttonset() impacted by Latest Chrome Update

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

A recent update by Google for their Chrome browser (31.0.1650.57 m) has caused an issue with jQuery's buttonset() where buttons are now showing vertically rather than horizontally as they should.

I found a work-around which is to set the 'display' css attribute to 'inline-block' after the initial buttonset() call.  Attempts to set this attribute prior to this call are ignored (though they worked fine for prior versions of Chrome and work well in FireFox).

My question is whether others have experienced this and if so, can they shed light on why this is happening and whether there is a better way of addressing this than with my work-around?

Comment: I don't believe this is an issue with chrome, it's likely an issue with your own personal CSS style sheets, because I have the 31.0.1650.57 m distribution and [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8Ev7/) works fine.

Comment: i didn't see it on official plugin's page, seems to work as expected: http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/button/

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - You are not using buttonset() just button().  Your suggestion to just try a basic example using this is good though!  That will separate where the issue lies (though it was working fine before the Chrome update).

Comment: @A.Wolff - Yes, I see what you mean.  The buttonset() does work correctly for me from the jQuery page on the latest Chrome so I will dig in deeper.  Thanks.

Comment: It appears to be an anomaly when using an old version of Bootstrap (v2.2.2 but also a problem with v2.3.2 I believe) with jQuery UI - but only on new versions of Chrome.  Goes away with latest Bootstrap (v3.x).  Unfortunately I can't upgrade right now so my work-around will have to do until I can.